# Controle remoto de um Android é tecnicamente possível?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Hoje vi o seguinte vídeo: **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9J7GpVQCfms**

Mostra um bracelete que projeta a tela de um celular Android pareado no braço do usuário. Este então pode manipular o celular movendo o dedo em seu braço.

O vídeo me parece claramente uma montagem (em vários momentos a projeção da tela não acompanha corretamente o movimento da câmera e o aparelho responde excessivamente rápido às entradas). Mas [**a empresa existe**](http://www.cicret.com/) e está arrecadando fundos para lançar um protótipo, então é possível que meramente tenham feito um vídeo promocional sem ter o protótipo pronto.

O que me deixou em dúvida é, assumindo que seja tudo real, como eles fariam um aplicativo que faz streaming da tela do Android e permite disparar eventos de gesture no aparelho? Isso é mesmo possível? Ou seria uma solução apenas para aparelhos com root e que tenham sido modificados de alguma forma? (Se isso é possível, por que empresas como o TeamViewer ainda não fizeram um cliente de controle remoto para o Android?)

Comment: Acho a ideia muito interessante. Mas acho que o **AirDroid** (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=pt_BR) já permite controlar o dispositivo pelo browser.

Comment: @Wakim ele permite enviar comandos ao celular e obter respostas, mas nunca ver a tela do aparelho ou controlar outros aplicativos. Dá para listar os contatos, ver notificações e transferir arquivos. Esse tipo de coisa apenas. Experimente instalar ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal tem mais coisas estranhas nesse projeto além desse. Um deles é que o ângulo de projeção é no mínimo "suspeito". A mínima inclinação do bracelete vai mudar as proporções da tela absurdamente. E se eles acharam um meio de compensar isso com software ou mesmo hardware, provavelmente daria pra fazer alguma coisa muito mais poderosa do que isso para por no mercado. Essa coisa do ângulo já é um dilema pros grandes fabricantes de projetor do mercado há anos. Como eles mesmos mencionam na página, eles não tem protótipo ainda. Depois que tiverem, podemos examinar melhor ;)

Comment: @Bacco, meu medo é que isso tudo seja um golpe. Porque eles pedem doações para o protótipo direto em uma conta do paypal (em vez de algo como o kickstarter). E o projeto inteiro me parece absurdo demais, em muitos pontos.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal juro que não tinha lido os comentários antes de escrever minha respostas, mas concordo com você, também acho que é golpe. Ainda pretendo atualizar minha resposta com mais imagens, outras explicações e fatos.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Isso me parece mais um trabalho para o MythBusters, mas vou me arriscar em uma resposta.

## Sobre o vídeo

> O vídeo me parece claramente uma montagem.

Com certeza é. Mas até então nada de errado nisso.

Suponha uma empresa que tem uma ideia e acha que venderá milhões, então após algumas pesquisas essa empresa conclui que o projeto é viavel e iniciam o desenvolvimento. Entretanto como em muitas das vezes essas ideias partem de pequenas *startups* elas não tem dinheiro para investir, então o que eles fazem é um vídeo promocional para deixar bem claro qual é a ideia deles e divulgam atrás de investidores que resolverem apostar na ideia.

De forma similar, em *stands* de venda de apartamento em condomínios, existem as maquetes, que não têm a intenção de se passarem por protótipos, mas tem como objetivo ilustrar a ideia da construtora.

### Quem seriam os investidores?

Existe um site chamado [Kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com). Ele é um exemplo de uma ideia muito interessante, chamada *crowdfunding*. *Crowdfunding* é uma derivação de *crowdsourcing*, onde uma organização usa o talento e tempo de centenas, milhares ou milhões de pessoas para criar ou melhorar um produto ou um serviço. Fonte: [Time](http://www.time.com/time/magazine/article/0,9171,1838768,00.html). Wikipedia é um belo exemplo de um *crowdsourcing*.

De forma similar, o Kickstarter usa o *crowdfunding* para pagar por projetos criativos solicitando pequenas doações do *crowd*, em tradução livre, do *povão*, que são investidores anônimos visitantes do site.

### Um caso de "sucesso"

Um projeto que ficou muito famoso no Kickstarter foi o [Mighty Mug](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/jayme39/mighty-mug-the-mug-that-wont-fall/description), que prometia fazer uma caneca que não tombava nunca, ideal para os desastrados.

Eles chegaram a fazer alguns protótipos e o vídeo bombou no YouTube. A meta inicial deles de arrecadar U$10.000,00 (dez mil dólares) foi ultrapassada em mais de 10 vezes. Sim, eles conseguiram mais de US$100.000,00 (cem mil dólares) de mais de 2.000 pessoas que também apostaram no produto.

Um sucesso!! Ou talvez não...

### Nem tudo que reluz é ouro

Há cerca de um mês as canecas começaram a ser enviadas para os investidores, e os problemas começaram a surgir, foram desde falta de número de rastreio dos envios, envios para endereços errados e o pior de todos: **o produto não atendeu às expectativas.**

Veja um dos diversos comentários de reclamação dos investidores após receberem o produto:

> I will NEVER support a kickstarter project ever after this experience with Mighty Mug. I finally get a product that is defective. The top leaks so bad that any liquid just pours out. USELESS! No response from Jayme and no help from Kickstarter.

Em tradução livre:

> Eu NUNCA mais vou apoiar outro projeto do kickstarter novamente após essa experiência com a Mighty Mug. Eu finalmente recebi meu produto, mas está com defeito. A fenda de cima é tão ruim que qualquer líquido vaza para fora. INÚTIL. Sem resposta do Jayme (o fundador) e nenhuma ajuda do Kickstarter.

Autor: alguém muito zangado que investiu na Mighty Mug.

Link: [Comentários dos investidores](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/jayme39/mighty-mug-the-mug-that-wont-fall/comments).

Infelizmente, até o momento o produto não deu muito certo.

### Cadê a pulseira no Kickstarter?

Aí que tá. Ela não está no Kickstarter pois não se trata de um *crowdfunding*. A empresa não está oferecendo nem prometendo protótipos, está apenas arrecadando doações.

A única coisa que eles afirmam é que a pulseira poderá ser desenvolvida se eles arrecadarem um montante de €700.000,00 (setecentos mil euros), o que equivale a cerca de R$2.300.000,00 (dois milhões e trezentos mil reais), na cotação de hoje.

A única promessa da empresa, e que já vem sendo cumprida é que os <strike>trouxas dos</strike> doadores terão seus nomes exibidos em um [muro da fama](http://www.cicret.com/wordpress/?page_id=18592), que nada mais é que uma lista de nomes em uma tabela <strike>tosquíssima</strike> em uma das páginas do site deles.

Mas... e se eles arrecadarem o dinheiro e não conseguirem desenvolver nem sequer um protótipo? Bem, não vejo escrito em nenhum lugar a garantia do protótipo, e por mais que ele um dia ele exista, será de propriedade da empresa, e não dos doadores.

## Implicações técnicas do desenvolvimento da pulseira

### 1. Streaming

*Streaming* em si provavelmente será o menor dos seus problemas, pois do mesmo jeito que você pode ligar seu celular em um HDMI e visualizar sua tela em uma TV, você pode muito bem enviar a imagem da tela para uma outra saída que não o cabo de dados.

> Minha avaliação do requisito: Superável.

#### *Problema 1: Segurança*

A segurança poderá ser uma problemática nessa situação, pois fazer *streaming* da tela através de dispositivos de terceiros pode permitir que o mesmo armazene imagens enquanto você digita senhas no teclado virtual.

Não chega a ser um impeditivo, pois da mesma maneira que confiamos nossos dados às fabricantes de celulares teríamos que confiar nossos dados ao fabricante da pulseira, mas não deixa de ser uma preocupação extra que devemos ter.

> Minha avaliação do problema: Superável.

### 2. Projeção

Projeção de imagens não é nenhuma novidade para nós, mas não desse jeito. Posso listar alguns problemas que pensei:

#### *Problema 2: O ângulo de incidência da luz projetada é muito inclinado*

[image: luz incidindo muito inclinada]

Isso quer dizer que a parte do braço que estiver mais próxima do projetor receberá muito mais luz do que o restante do braço, o que faria com que a imagem ficasse forte perto do projetor e fraca longe dele.

Além do mais, a imagem estaria projetada em diferentes distâncias, o que quer dizer que precisaríamos de uma lente projetora multi-focal, para focar tanto de perto quanto de longe, ao mesmo tempo. Coisa que não existe hoje.

> Minha avaliação do problema: Impeditivo. Acredito que não há solução para isso.

#### *Problema 3:  O ângulo de projeção pode variar*

[image: angulo variando]

Se a pulseira estiver muito larga, muito apertada, ou simplesmente se movimentar pelo braço, implica que o ângulo da projeção deve acompanhar esses movimentos, e isso envolve muitos sensores de proximidade e muitos ajustes na projeção. Algo que ao meu ver é completamente inviável.

> Minha avaliação do problema: Impeditivo. Acredito que não há solução para isso.

#### *Problema 4: A lente fica muito próxima da projeção*

Isso quer dizer duas coisas:

***4.1. O ângulo de abertura da lente tem que ser muito grande;***

Pra poder projetar à curtas distâncias, a abertura da lente deve ser muito grande.

Na fotogradia, uma lente "Super Grande Angular" proporciona uma abertura de até 95º. Já as lentes "Olho de peixe" capturam imagens em um ângulo que pode ser de até 180º. Fonte: [Techtudo: Saiba o significado das siglas e números da abertura de lentes de câmeras](http://www.techtudo.com.br/dicas-e-tutoriais/noticia/2014/04/saiba-o-significado-das-siglas-e-numeros-da-abertura-de-lentes-de-cameras.html)

Mas todo mundo sabe como que fica a foto não é mesmo?

[image: olho de peixe]

Vamos calcular a abertura da lente da suposta pulseira. Por base nas imagens do vídeo, considere que a distância de 1 cm do projetor até a projeção, e que a largura da projeção é de 4 cm.

[image: distancias da projeção]

Que resulta no seguinte cálculo:

> Cateto oposto = 4 cm / 2 = 2 cm
>   Cateto adjacente = 1cm
>
> tg = cateto oposto / cateto adjacente; logo:
>
> tg α = 2/1 ∴ α ≈ 65º

Portanto, a abertura da lente projetora deveria ser de cerca de 130º. Que deixaria a tela com uma aparência bem estranha, similar à da foto do olho de peixe.

***4.2. A lente tem que ser capaz de dar foco à distâncias curtíssimas.***

Para dar foco à curtas distâncias a lente precisa fechar bastante o diafragma, mas fechar o diafragma implica em diminuição do ângulo de abertura da lente, o que quer dizer que os itens 4.1 e 4.2 são conflitantes, e consequentemente, não é possível ter os dois simultaneamente. Fonte: [Mania de fotografar: Como fazer uma fotografia de macro? Dicas para fotografar macro](http://www.maniadefotografar.com.br/noticia.asp?url=136#ixzz3LbiOTj2q)

> Minha avaliação do problema: Impeditivo. Acredito que não há solução para isso.

#### *Problema 5: A superfície do nosso braço não é plana*

Nosso braço não se parece nada nada com uma parede, onde normalmente ocorrem as projeções. As irregularidades da superfície do nosso braço poderiam causar desde sombras na projeção da imagem até imagens completamente distorcidas.

Será que alguém teria paciência para ler textos inteiros que mais se parecem com *captchas* infinitas?

> Minha avaliação do problema: Gravissímo. Não vale a pena o investimento.

#### *Problema 6: Projetores costumam funcionar bem no escuro*

Os projetores que estamos acostumados a ver em salas de aulas e reuniões, precisam de pouca luz competindo com a sua iluminação, caso contrário a projeção fica quase invisível. No caso de um micro projetor a tendência é só piorar, já que a potência da lâmpada tende a ser menor.

> Minha avaliação do problema: Dispositivo se restringiria basicamente a ambientes internos com pouquíssima iluminação. Perderia muito mercado com isso tornando sua produção praticamente inviável.

#### *Problema 7:  A imagem ficará cortada quando o dedo tocar o braço*

[image: dedo cobrindo projeção]

<sup>(Imagem representando os problemas 6 e 7, juntos)</sup>

Bem diferente do vídeo de divulgação, não?

> Minha avaliação do problema: Dá pra conviver com isso. Mas a aplicação perderia muito do seu encanto e se tornaria muito menos atrativa do que o vídeo sugere.

### 3. Gestures

Se chegamos a nos preocupar com esse ponto, é por que resolvemos todos os problemas anteriores. Logo, da mesma forma que a pulseira seria inteligente o suficiente para conseguir projetar uma imagem plana sob circunstâncias tão adversas, ela teria sensores o suficiente para conseguir identificar onde um objeto interferiu na projeção com um ângulo acentuado o suficiente sobre a superfície para ser considerado um toque no "tela".

> Minha avaliação do requisito: Superável.

### 4. Root

> Ou seria uma solução apenas para aparelhos com root e que tenham sido modificados de alguma forma?

Se esse produto realmente fosse fabricado, diria que, se o root fosse uma obrigação, isso seria um problema que não duraria por muito tempo. Podemos partir do princípio que esse produto seria tão revolucionário que as empresas que desenvolvem os sistemas operacionais dos celulares fariam de tudo para facilitar o compatibilidade com os seus dispositivos, e possivelmente até fechariam parcerias para vender combos de celulares que já acompanham a tal pulseira.

Logo, eu diria que essa preocupação por hora é irrelevante.

> Minha avaliação do requisito: Superável.

## Conclusão

Ressaltados os seguinte pontos:

- Existem inúmeras dificuldades no desenvolvimento do projeto, algumas que eu julgo que tornariam o projeto inviável;
- Nada que garante legalmente que a empresa usará o dinheiro arrecadado no desenvolvimento do produto.

Sem querer duvidar da idoneidade de ninguém, eu apenas gostaria de concluir que alguém mal intencionado pode ganhar muito dinheiro em cima de promessas e nenhuma obrigação legal e compromissos.

Meu veredito é:

[image: mito detonado]

Comment: quis dizer que aquela projeção é generosa, pq apesar de mostrar a obstrução, a parte não obstruida tem regioes escuras, o que seria impossivel na realidade. Um projetor só consegue ir da cor da pele pra mais claro. Não existe nada parecido com "facho escurecedor de luz", a não ser em desenho animado.

Comment: Ah sim, entendi agora. Estou anotando todos os seu comentários, acho que minha resposta vai aumentar bem de tamanho! rs..

Comment: @Bacco na verdade eu só cortei parte da projeção, o resto quem fez foi a própria empresa

Comment: Sei disso. Só comentei que vc foi generoso em nao consertar esse outro defeito, pq no mundo real seria bem pior.

Comment: Estou arrecadando fundos para construir um "facho escurecedor de luz", @Bacco. Quem quiser colaborar pode contribuir com bitcoins postadas em comentários aqui no SOpt.

Comment: @bfavaretto aproveite e faça um moto-contínuo/perpétuo pra alimentar a lâmpada escurecedora :D

Comment: Em boas condições de iluminação, e com um "projetor hiper intenso ™", mal e mal daria pra chegar nisso: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EVfKT.jpg DETALHE: Se contar a curvatura do braço, vc vai ver que a posição da lente não permitiria uma imagem tão grande. Neste tamanho mesmo, o próprio braço obstruiria os 4 bicos da imagem.

Comment: @bacco é problema que não acaba mais! Ainda falta falar da luz escura, da intensidade da luz e dos pelos, apesar que os pelos pode se usar o argumento que você pode usar a pulseira para o lado de dentro do braço, onde não há tantos deles assim. E além do mais me passam pela cabeça várias outras forma de derrubar esse mito, como bateria por exemplo, e outros ainda relacionado a lente super fantástica que não existe nem em Júpiter, rs.. Mas meus próximos passos são as fontes e as imagens.

Comment: @Bacco sim, tem uma parte do vídeo que o cara tira zoom do mapa, mas um dedo tá cobrindo o outro da projeção, pensei em pegar essa imagem pra editar tb e usar na resposta.

Comment: @Bacco valeu pela imagem editada! me economizou um belo de um trabalho :)

Comment: Haha! Esse "MITO DETONADO" me chamou muita atenção! Boas análises! Realmente a ideia do dedo sobre a tela (Montagem que por sinal ficou muito boa!) cortando a tela não tinha imaginado. Parabéns!

Answer (score 7):

## Emulando eventos de toque

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> nesta imagem acima eu acionei o modo desenvolvedor "mostrar local do ponteiro", note as coordenadas de posição sendo mostradas, seria perfeitamente possível utilizar informações como essa para emulação de toques.

Sim, é possível, pois como podes ver [nesta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7001356/2319589) há meios de **simular eventos** *gesture¹* no android, por isso existem aplicativos [como esse](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/android-hovering-control-app/) que setam ações para determinados eventos, estas ações podem ser escutadas por aplicativos instalados como um **serviço** no android, pois estes aplicativos rodam em *background* no seu aparelho, e utilizam GestureListener's para captar seus movimentos no aparelho.

## Quanto a parte do streaming:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como você falou do TeamViewer, pois é, ele mesmo tem uma solução para isso, que seria o [suporte à dispositivos móveis](http://www.teamviewer.com/pt/products/mobile-device-support.aspx), por isso você pode entender que mesmo sem root, você consegue ter o streaming da tela do dispositivo.

## Agora a questão do "remoto"

Pois bem, a maioria dos aplicativos que enviam comandos para o aparelho precisam de root, porém há meios como SMS Tasks que você pode enviar sms para o seu aparelho e ele reconhecer a string e executar tarefas mediante a isto, porém a performance é baixíssima, da mesma forma, existem alguns aplicativos que controlam ações no celular via wifi, como o AirDroid, mas acredito que o próprio [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/pt/products/mobile-device-support.aspx) seja o melhor indicado para se basear nessa questão pois ele tem o mouse do computador como ponto em que você pode realizar todos os eventos de toque singulares, quanto aos múltiplos, não sei ao certo, mas daí já da pra se basear e ter um começo para uma futura implementação diferente.

## Sensor de proximidade(toque)

[image: calculo da posição da proximidade]

Bom, no caso do [Cicret](http://www.cicret.com) ele utiliza 8 sensores de proximidade longa que capturam a presença e enviam para o processador do qual utiliza a placa wifi para enviar os comandos para o aparelho, [como podes ver aqui](http://youtu.be/9J7GpVQCfms?t=1m52s) mas acredito que o Arduino esteja envolvido neste esquema, pois [com Arduino é possível implementar sensores de proximidade](http://www.instructables.com/id/Simple-IR-proximity-sensor-with-Arduino/).

## Projeção(e.g. Data Show)

O cicret utiliza o *pico projector* para realizar a projeção do streaming, por isso podemos acreditar que seja verdade, porém acredito que não tenha tanta qualidade de vídeo como está parecendo, por causa da luz, quem sabe em um ambiente escuro sim, porém em um ambiente claro fica difícil acreditar que isto funcione bem, porém [podes ver aqui](http://www.slashgear.com/touchpico-thinks-you-need-android-on-a-tiny-projector-28338844/) algo sobre o pico e como ele pode funcionar.

## Conclusão

Bom, resumindo, atualmente já existem todas estas tecnologias citadas acima, mas acredito que a única que envolva tudo isso em um só dispositivo, seria esse tal de cicret, vale a pena entrar a fundo nisto, se você busca entender como funciona, pois é algo inovador e bem interessante, espero ter ajudado.

¹: "Gesture" significa gestos, que é o objeto principal de controle de eventos que envolvem o toque em forma de gestos, movimentações, no android.

Comment: 1. A pergunta mostra como criar um evento de toque, mas ele sé injetado por essa API: `view.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);`, ou seja: você precisa ter uma view alvo, não pode injetar um evento global ou mesmo fora da sua própria aplicação. | 2. O aplicativo [Hovering Controls Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.golgorz.hoveringcontrolsfree) (veja o vídeo) não cria toques. Ele no máximo abre aplicativos. Mas parece ter uma versão que usa algo com ROOT para controlar adicionar gestos em outros aplicativos. Isso talvez seja um começo.

Comment: 3. Sobre o streaming do video, eu testei a solução deles e não é algo global (vide comentário na outra resposta). 4. O pico projetor é interessante, mas até mesmo ele só funciona bem no escuro. Digo.. como esse bracelete vai projetar preto na pele da pessoa?

Comment: Pois é @GuilhermeBernal com root tudo fica mais facil(no ponto de vista funcional) mas do mesmo jeito que o aplicativo capta o seu movimento ele pode ao invés de abrir um aplicativo, ele pode despachar a própria ação que você executou, entende?

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal TeamViewer é sim, é conexão remota, tem a parte de screenshot e tal mas ele tem a opção de vc controlar diretamente e usar o mouse pra clicar nas coisas etc.. eu e mais uns daqui da empresa já usamos

Comment: Mas como? A nível de código

Comment: Agora sobre o pico, como eu te disse, na ausência de luz fica perfeito, mas não sei se ele tem capacidade real de emitir em ambientes claros, agora o preto me veio a cabeça como algo quase que impossível, como uma negação de raios luz (algo bem além da tecnologia atual) mas quem sabe ele consiga, eu não pesquisei a fundo sobre ele

Comment: Se eu posso fazer um aplicativo que seja um serviço que injete toques no aparelho e capture a tela a vontade, então eu posso perfeitamente abrir o aplicativo de banco do usuário e transferir tudo para minha conta enquanto ele não estiver olhando. Entende? Um aplicativo que seja capaz de controlar outros é uma enorme falha de segurança.

Comment: Sabe os android.permission ? então, quando você instala um aplicativo no seu aparelho, ele mostra TUDO QUE ELE PODE FAZER no caso, e em alguns casos mostra em evidência que aquilo pode ser até perigoso, dá varios alertas e tal mas na verdade é você que aceita instalar o aplicativo ou não, porém há alguns casos que o android acha perigoso demais e bloqueia, daí viria o root nessa história toda.

Comment: Provavelmente o tal do cicret vai precisar de um estardalhaço de papéis e licensas e autorizações e permissões do android pra conseguir se instalar e funcionar **sem root**

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal não temos acesso ao código fonte do aplicativo por isso não sabemos exatamente a nível de código como implementar essa função, mas sabemos que é possível, como programadores, entendemos que se é possível captar um evento e identifica-lo e classifica-lo podemos também executa-lo. Este contexto foi baseado como uma afirmação que "é possível" respondendo esta sua pergunta.

Comment: O QuickSupport do TeamViewer de fato tem controle remoto, mas requer root para funcionar. Fora isso, parece não haver como. Nenhuma permissão do android permite esse nível de acesso e nenhuma API pública permite injetar toques ou capturar telas fora do aplicativo. Sendo assim, a unica forma de esse bracelete funcionar seria **com root**? Se não, como seria a implementação disso?

Comment: Dizer que "nenhuma permissão do android permite esse nível de acesso" soa meio leviano, sabe naturalmente acredito que não, mas acredito que exista meios alternativos para isto, talvez não uma permissão "normal" ou talvez uma permissão diferenciada que seria **exclusiva** para este intuito, pois acredito que em cima de todo este trabalho de marketing da cicret eles devem ter consciência junto com o android que haja uma **permissão exclusiva** para o aplicativo em sí. Afinal, entendemos que na programação tudo é possível (até que se prove o contrário).

Comment: Testei aqui e verifiquei que o TeamViewer QuickSupport só tem suporte para algumas fabricantes (http://www.teamviewer.com/pt/help/341-How-can-I-control-my-Android-device-with-TeamViewer.aspx), que provavelmente devem ceder permissões para este tipo ferramenta, mas já no Android "Puro" (Como a linha Nexus e Motorola), não consegui utilizar. Segundo a TechTudo (http://www.techtudo.com.br/noticias/noticia/2014/11/android-50-vai-permitir-gravar-videos-da-tela-do-celular-sem-root.html), a ideia da Google é permitir gravações da tela, o que talvez possibilite um aplicativo usar este recurso.

Comment: Vale lembrar que tal recurso, na minha opinião, é uma boa falha de segurança do dispositivo, integrar aos desenvolvedores uma ferramenta tão poderosa como essa. Nem a gravação de ligações o Android possui (descontinuado desde a versão 2.3). Somente através de `root`.

Answer (score 1):

Respondendo a sua pergunta:

> Se isso é possível, por que empresas como o TeamViewer ainda não fizeram um cliente de controle remoto para o Android?

Sim existe cliente para acessar dispositivos Android, feito pela própria TeamViewer.

"Com o suporte a dispositivos móveis do TeamViewer para Android, você controla dispositivos móveis remotamente¹ e consegue ver exatamente o que o usuário do dispositivo está vendo. Outros recursos incluem: visualização aprimorada do painel de controle, possibilidade de encerrar processos remotamente no dispositivo móvel e recuperação de arquivos do dispositivo Android."

Fonte [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/pt/products/mobile-device-support.aspx).

Comment: Eu testei o sistema deles e por padrão não há compartilhamento de telas ou controle remoto de nenhum tipo. O QuickSupport envia dados do aparelho para o "controlador" e este pode se comunicar com o usuário através de um chat. Screenshots podem ser enviadas, mas manualmente, pelo usuário no celular.        Quanto ao compartilhamento em tempo real mencionado, é uma biblioteca para ser incorporada em aplicativos de terceiros. Ou seja: é um código embutido no próprio aplicativo para que este envie ativamente suas próprias telas. Não é possível receber nada fora desde aplicativo

Comment: AI que tu se engana, pode sim, e inclusive alem do TeamViewer tem o AirDroid que permite controlar no computador a tela do celular

Comment: Amigo @LucasMotta, AirDroid não controla a tela do celular, apenas o gerenciamento de arquivos e periféricos do Android, nos quais já há permissões disponíveis para os desenvolvedores. Além disso, a opção "Captura de Tela" só funciona com `root`. Já o TeamViewer, [vide meu comentário](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42709/controle-remoto-de-um-android-%C3%A9-tecnicamente-poss%C3%ADvel#comment85969_43039)

Comment: @biio, já usou? Eu já usei e vi usando, dá sim pra controlar a tela do celular pelo computador. Inclusive da pra acessar todos os aplicativos incluindo a câmera. É como se fosse uma conexão de área de trabalho remota do windows.

Comment: Ah, desculpe pelo equívoco @MeuChapeu, meu celular é o Nexus 5 e está na versão Lollipop 5.0, que é incompatível com a ferramenta AirMirror. Provavelmente em outras versões ele possa ser compatível!

Comment: Tanto AirDroid quanto TeamViewer permitem controlar totalmente a tela do celular... Não por captura de tela nem por chat, e sim por compartilhamento de tela, por acesso remoto

Comment: Não sendo compatível com Android "Puro", torna-se uma ferramenta, digamos, limitada. Hoje baixei o aplicativo "Screen Recorder", no qual só é compatível com Lollipop. Podemos ver grandes avanços com relação à isso.